# share logic between projects in the same repo webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron

I am having a problem sharing logic between two projects in the same repo.

```
/project1
-- app.js (calling shared-code)
-- webpack here
/project2
-- shared-code.js
```

This is the repo

https://github.com/zhex900/mir-kiosk-electron/tree/node-ipc

`awsIoT` is referenced in `electronKiosk`

```
ERROR in ./src/electron/awsIoT/index.ts 51:33-80
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../awsIoT/src' in 'C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electronKiosk\src\electron\awsIoT'
resolve '../../../awsIoT/src' in 'C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electronKiosk\src\electron\awsIoT'
  using description file: C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electronKiosk\package.json (relative path: ./src/electron/awsIoT)
    using description file: C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electronKiosk\package.json (relative path: ./awsIoT/src)
      no extension
        C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electronKiosk\awsIoT\src doesn't exist
      .js
        C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electronKiosk\awsIoT\src.js doesn't exist
      .ts
        C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electronKiosk\awsIoT\src.ts doesn't exist
      .jsx
        C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electronKiosk\awsIoT\src.jsx doesn't exist
      .tsx
        C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electronKiosk\awsIoT\src.tsx doesn't exist
      .css
        C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electronKiosk\awsIoT\src.css doesn't exist
      .json
        C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electronKiosk\awsIoT\src.json doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electronKiosk\awsIoT\src doesn't exist
 @ ./src/electron/index.ts 40:15-34
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it.

I added

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".css", ".json"],
    alias: {
      awsIoT: path.resolve(__dirname, "../awsIoT/src")
    }
  },
```

https://geoffdavis.info/writing/how-to-import-modules-out-of-webpacks-scope